# Repeater carrier as access

Tags: repeater

I'm just getting into ham radio. I'm trying to connect to a repeater here in Ireland:

- Channel: RU260(RB10)
- Output: 433.250
- Input:   434.850
- Call sign:EI7SHR
- Access: Carrier

What does the "Carrier" mean here?

I was expecting a PL/CTCSS frequency.

Comment: "ham", when used to refer to amateur radio, (i.e. ham radio) is not an acronym.  No need to capitalize it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 5):

"Carrier access" just means that you do not need a CTCSS tone to access the repeater.  Your carrier brings up the repeater.

CTCSS access may reduce co-channel interference between repeaters if their coverage area overlaps, but it is not technically necessary for access.

Comment: Some repeaters use a burst tone (a short audible tone at the start of the transmission) or DTMF for access as well.